# Javascript run function one time in another function which sets as interval

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

hi i am using selenium chrome driver in my js. And i am checking value in website in every 2 seconds. here is my code. Value is checking every 2 seconds. and it has two value. like online or offline. i want write to text file for status changes. not for every check. here is my code. it is working but it save text file every two seconds. i want check every two seconds but i want save it in text only status changes. help me pls.

```
setInterval(MyControl, 2000);

function MyControl() {
  var x = browser.findElements(By.className("textclass")).then(function(divs) {
    // console.log("yy:",divs.length);
    var d = new Date();
    if (divs.length == 1) {
      divs.forEach(function(element) {
        element.getAttribute("title").then(function(text) {
          console.log(text, " Control Time :", d.toLocaleString());
          //    playSound();

          fs.appendFile('mytextfile.txt', text + " Control Time: " + d.toLocaleString() + '\n', function(err) {
            // console.log("/////////////////////////////////////");
            if (err) throw err;
          });
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log("There isnt any info :" + "Control Time :" + d.toLocaleString());

    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply condition writing the file on whether the current value differs from the previous value.

```
setInterval(MyControl, 2000);

let previousText = null;

function MyControl() {
  var x = browser.findElements(By.className("textclass")).then(function (divs) {
    // console.log("yy:",divs.length);
    var d = new Date();
    if (divs.length == 1) {
      divs.forEach(function (element) {
        element.getAttribute("title").then(function (text) {
          console.log(text, " Control Time :", d.toLocaleString());
          //    playSound();
          if (text != previousText)
            fs.appendFile('mytextfile.txt', text + " Control Time: " + d.toLocaleString() + '\n', function (err) {
              // console.log("/////////////////////////////////////");
              if (err) throw err;
            });
          previousText = text;
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log("There isnt any info :" + "Control Time :" + d.toLocaleString());

    }
  });
}
```

Also note that the above rewritten in proper JS style is much more readable:

```
setInterval(MyControl, 2000);

let previousText = null;

function MyControl() {
  browser.findElements(By.className('textclass')).then(divs => {
    if (divs.length !== 1)
      return;
    let date = new Date();
    div[0].getAttribute('title').then(text => {
      if (text !== previousText)
        fs.appendFile('mytextfile.txt', `${text} Control Time: ${date.toLocaleString()}\n`, err => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      previousText = text;
    });
  });
}
```